# Using a string to represent a tag in a BeautifulSoup object

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Say I have a BeautifulSoup Object named `bs4`. To use bs4's `find_all_next` function on a `p` tag I would just do:

```
bs4.p.find_all_next(string = True)
```

I want to throw this in a for loop for all tags available in the webpage:

```
temp_set = set()
for x in bs4.find_all():
    temp_set.add(x.name) # Store only tag name, no dupes, order doesn't matter
```

However when it comes time use it in a bs4 object:

```
for x in temp_set:
    bs4.x.find_all_next(string = True) # x is supposed to represent the tag name; attribute error
```

I know that there is no tag 'x' that exists, which is why I get the attribute error, is there anything I can do to make the 'x' in the loop symbolize the tag it's supposed to be representing as if I print it to console?

Comment: You can use the `try` statement to catch exceptions and manage it from there, refer [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions).

Comment: @BernardL I could do that, and match the tag name to a string that represents the tag and explicitly call `bs4.[tag].bs4Function` , but that would guarantee an exception for every iteration of the loop. I don't think that's the best course of action, a way to allow a variable in place of the tag name in the bs4 object would be preferable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

document states [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr):

getattr(x, 'foobar') is equivalent to x.foobar

So when I tried it, I just looped through:

```
getattr(bs4, x).find_all_next(string = True)
```

as the document says is equivalent to `bs4.x.find_all_next(string = True)` with x as the variable

I'm not sure what you want to do with it from there.

Not all the items in your set will work, so I just looped, threw them into a list, and then threw the exceptions into a list too just to see which didn't work. And 'select' will give a `AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'find_all_next'`

so basically, here's what I did in that last section. Again, do what you want, but you'll loop through `getattr(bs4, x).find_all_next(string = True)`

```
final_list = []
failed_x = []

for x in temp_set:
    try:
        final_list.append(list(getattr(bs4, x).find_all_next(string = True)))
    except:
        failed_x.append(x)
        continue
```

Comment: Again, I'm aware and not worried about exceptions, I have a filter for that. However the getattr fixed the problem.